# If Bulma is a basic CSS framework, how is npm used/leveraged?

Tags: bulma

I'm about to rewrite a pretty basic legacy site and would like to use Bulma as my HTML/CSS framework.   The Bulma quick start shows a simple page with their included .css.  That works fine, but I need things such as a [horizontal navigation bar](https://github.com/hunzaboy/bulma-megamenu/blob/master/README.md).

Most of the Bulma examples begin with instructions to use `npm` to install components.  The git download also includes a sass folder.  Is NPM and/or SASS basic requirements for using the Bulma framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NPM/SASS are not required to use the bulma framework. All you need to do is link to the bulma stylesheet:

`<link rel="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css">`

Then add mega-menu's css to your page:

```
<style>
   .navbar-item.is-mega {
     position: static;
   }
   .navbar-item.is-mega .is-mega-menu-title {
     margin-bottom: 0;
     padding: .375rem 1rem;
   }
 </style>
```